How to import multiple *.CSV files into SQL Server | Combine all the files into 1 | Export the resultant data as CSV
I am using SQL for the first time and have no prior knowledge in coding or SQL so please bear with me.
I have about 70 CSVs and each CSV have same columns and starts with the header row.
I want to do the following:

Import all the CSVs from folder into SQL database. All the CSVs live here: "E:\Export for Global Model\EAST".
Combine all the CSVs into one file. So, I want to keep the header row from the first CSV and ignore the header row for all remaining 69 CSvs.
Once the CSVs are combined, I want to export that resultant one file as csv which will then be used in another planning tool.

I tried going through similar answers on the stackoverflow but can't make any of the query work.
